# How to make sure Service gets called from a specific activity

Tags: android, android-service

In android how to make sure that the `service` that I have in the application will get called only through an `activity` that is within the app.

(In other words I want to limit the service to get played by only a certain activity & not even by other activities within that app)

I tried studying `Intent-filters` but got a bit confused.

Can someone please suggest, if possible with an example?

**Thank You**

Answer (score 0):

Use Context.[startService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startService%28android.content.Intent%29)(Intent service) to start the service from your activity.
Despite the name it doesnt only start the service. If the service is running already, it just calls it.

From the service perspective, the service will then call its onStartCommand(...) method.

Only an activity within the same application can call/start a service this way.

Answer (score 0):

If you set `exported="false"` in your `<service .. />` element of AndroidManifest.xml, the service cannot be called by activities outside your own app.

I know of no way to limit access to any particular activity within the app, but this seems a less pressing concern. Supposedly you can trust your own code?

Comment: actually my concern is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14903374/android-activity-also-calling-other-service-of-the-application-which-is-not-ca)